How to change the SQL Server name
I would like to change the computer name and the SQL Server name.
For now, I only changed the hostname and the server name with the step below.

Changed computer hostname.

  sp_dropserver 'WIN2012\MSSQLSERVER' 
  GO 
  sp_addserver 'WIN2012_TEST\MSSQLSERVER', local 
  GO



But I found the login name and the SQL Server agent didn't change.
So, I would like to know all the steps If I want to change the computer name and the SQL Server name.
Could anyone provide the steps?
Thank you
